# Filling in a data frame using else if

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to automate a process using R so it can be done rapidly with new data. I have a data frame with an empty label column, that can have 4 labels based on the size of the value in column 1.

I currently have this

```
testdata <- as.data.frame(document)
COL1 <- testdata$COL1
Label <- testdata$Label

for(i in 1:length(COL1)){
  if(i > 25){
    Label <- "Label 1"
  } else if(i <= 25){
    Label <- "Label 2"
  } else if(i <= 15){
    Label <- "Label 3"
  } else if (i < 7){
    Label <-" Label 4"
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is the whole column is filling in as "Label 1" (the i > 25 data label) no matter which order I put them in they all fill in with "Label 1".

I am assuming there is an error with the i > 25 statement but I can't see it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more clear if you use a case_when type of function, it is basicly a chain of if else statements.

```
library(tidyverse)

testdata %>%
 mutate(filter_col = case_when(
    COL1 <= 7  ~ "Label 4",
    COL1 <= 15 ~ "Label 3",
    COL1 <= 25 ~ "Label 2",
    COL1 > 25  ~ "Label 1",
    )
  )
```

Comment: this worked as well, thank you. I need to get better with tidyverse, the code always looks so nice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe avoiding using loops would make it safer and less error-prone?

```
testdata$Label[COL1 > 0] = 'Label 4'
testdata$Label[COL1 > 6] = 'Label 3'
testdata$Label[COL1 > 15] = 'Label 2'
testdata$Label[COL1 > 25] = 'Label 1'
``
```

Comment: This worked well, however, I am aiming to edit in additional ifs and equations (in later columns) based on the value in column 1, will this work without the loops?

Comment: should be yes, you can combine different conditions if you want: testdata$Label[COL1 > 0 & col4 >0.2] if you also want col1 being larger than 0 AND col4 larger than 0.2 (just an exemple)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `i` is just reflecting the row number (order) not the value of `COL1`

There are a few ways of doing this, but I try something vectorized like this:

```
ifelse(testdata$COL1  > 25,
       "Label 1",
       ifelse(testdata$COL1  <= 2,
              "Label 2",
              ifelse(testdata$COL1<= 15,
                     "Label 3",
                     ifelse(testdata$COL1 < 7,
                            "Label 4",
                            "")
                     )
              )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is the base R function for this. The difference between the variables (`label_factor`, `label_char`) is their type.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(30, 0, 30))
df$label_factor <- cut(df$x, breaks = c(-Inf, 7, 15, 25, Inf), labels = paste("Label", 1:4))
df$label_char <- as.character(df$label_factor)
df
#x label_factor label_char
#1   8.627326      Label 2    Label 2
#2  23.649154      Label 3    Label 3
#3  12.269308      Label 2    Label 2
#4  26.490522      Label 4    Label 4
```